# How do I scan in numbers to an array from a file?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, scanf

Say I have a file with the numbers:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -1

I want to read in that file and store all the values of that file, stopping at the control variable -1.

So if I printed that array to another file it would look like:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

This gives me all the numbers, but it has -1 included. How can I drop off the -1?

```
   int arr[100];
   int n;
   while (scanf("%d",&arr[n]) > 0)
       n++;
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add the `> 0` condition: this would give you undefined behavior. In order to ignore the negative one, you could add a separate check inside the loop, after reading the number, like this:

```
while (scanf("%d", &arr[n]) != EOF) {
    if (arr[n] > 0) {
        n++;
    }
}
```

Since the array `arr` has fixed size, it would be a good idea to guard against overruns, like this:

```
while (n < 100 && scanf("%d", &arr[n]) != EOF) {
    if (arr[n] > 0) {
        n++;
    }
}
```

This loop would stop if you reach 100 before the file ends. Note that you also need to initialize `n` to zero before the loop to avoid undefined behavior.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/CO9H8O).

Comment: Doing that gives me an infinite loop since there is no condition for it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[100];
int n;
int temp;
do
{
    scanf("%d",&temp);
    if(temp != -1)
    {
        arr[n] = temp;
    }
   n++;
}while(temp != -1 && n < 100);
```